# Drop down menu directing to same URL

Tags: javascript, velo

I have created a drop down menu with multiple options to chose from. 
However what ever option I chose it directs me to the same URL. In this case the last written code. Could someone please tell me what I have missed in the code?

```js
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';

$w.onReady(function () {
    $w("#dropdown1").onChange((event, $w) => {
        console.log(event.target.value); //iPhone X
        wixLocation.to("/iphonex");
    });
});
$w.onReady(function () {
    $w("#dropdown1").onChange((event, $w) => {
        console.log(event.target.value); //iPhone XS
        wixLocation.to("/iphonexs");
    });
});
$w.onReady(function () {
    $w("#dropdown1").onChange((event, $w) => {
        console.log(event.target.value); //iPhone XS MAX
        wixLocation.to("/iphonexsmax");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one event handler. You need to go to the value

If you have more than one, the last one is executed

```js
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';

$w.onReady(function () {
    $w("#dropdown1").onChange((event, $w) => {
        var page = event.target.value); //"iPhone X" OR "iPhone XS" etc
        if (page) wixLocation.to("/"+page.replace(/\s+/g,"").toLowerCase());
    });
});
```

If you instead set the VALUE of the options to iphonex, iphonexs etc, then you can just do

```
    $w("#dropdown1").onChange((event, $w) => {
        var page = event.target.value); // "iphonex" OR "iphonexs" etc
        if (page) wixLocation.to("/"+page)
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out this weekend and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you mplungjan...I tried the bottom one and it words great.